# Point selection problem

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, editing, select

Using the selection button tool and selecting one point from a shapefile selects all points in that shapefile. Possible to select single points from the attribute table, Select by Attributes to select a single point, and will select a single point in editing mode. This is a new quirk. 10.3.1

Trying to recreate this (colleague in another state having the issue) and the only way I could was by setting the Selection Tolerance ridiculously high (default 3 pixels).

Comment: Do you see the same behavior for all point feature classes? Hard to know what's going on - that would be a show-stopper of a bug if it was wide-spread.

Comment: All, including polys.

Comment: Does this describe your problem (data frame = GCS, display units = UTM/MGRS/USNG)? http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000011966

Comment: I'd remove *.SB* files, spatial index can be corrupted

Answer (score 1):

You have potentially answered your own question - "Trying to recreate this (colleague in another state having the issue) and the only way I could was by setting the Selection Tolerance ridiculously high (default 3 pixels)."

2 Solutions

1. Check the selection tolerance and reduce it if it is high.
2. phloem (in the comments) provided a link an ESRI bug page which describes the exact problem you are having. The page contains instructions for a workaround: http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000011966